# A byte like object is required not str

Tags: python-3.x, geoip

Есть код:

```
import http.client
from geoip import geolite2
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("ifconfig.me")
conn.request("GET", "/ip")
ip = conn.getresponse().read()
match = geolite2.lookup(ip)
```

Выдает ошибку
`A byte like object is required not str`, что значит, что для функции требуется последовательность байтов, а не строка. Хотя переменная ip и содержит последовательность байтов, в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: На какой строке выдаёт-то?

Comment: @andreymal на последней